# How to manipulate the object inside the array using javascript?

Tags: javascript-objects

```
var arr = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Ahmed Malick', school: 'TEWGS' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Tehmeed Anwar', school: 'DGS' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Azhar Yameen', school: 'DGS' }
```

]

I want this output:
The student name is  his id is  and he studies in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please show me what kind of output you expect. Then i will try to solve it.

#### I'm not sure if this is what you want

```
var arr = [
  { id: 1, name: "Ahmed Malick", school: "TEWGS" },
  { id: 2, name: "Tehmeed Anwar", school: "DGS" },
  { id: 3, name: "Azhar Yameen", school: "DGS" },
];

arr.map((student) => {
      return `Name: ${student.name}, id: ${student.id}, he studies in: ${student.school}`;
    }).forEach((output) => {
      console.log(output);
});
```

#### If you want it in the DOM do this

```
let html = arr.map((student) => {
      return `<p><strong>Name</strong>: ${student.name}, <strong>id</strong>: ${student.id},<strong> he studies in</strong> ${student.school}</p>`;
    }).join("") 

document.createElement("div").innerHTML = html
```

Try thatGood luck

Comment: it works fine with console.log() but I wat the same result in DOM using `innerHTML` or `innerText` and etc

Comment: I've edited the answer, check it out, if you find this helpful please vote for it

Comment: Love you bro for your help @Crispen Gari